# Number field theoretical analogue of Riemann's Existence Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

This question is related to Riemann's Existence Theorem as cited in Neukirch, Schmidt et. al.: Cohomology of Number fields (10.5.1).

Let $k$ be a number field, $T \supseteq S \subseteq S_p \cup S_\infty$ be a set of primes of $k$ and $p$ a prime number. Then the canonical homomorphism

$$\Phi_{T,S}: \ast _{\mathfrak{p} \in T \setminus S (k_S(p))} T_\mathfrak{p}(k(p)\mid k) \to G(k_T(p)\mid k_S(p))$$

is an isomorphism.

> How can I see, that this homomorphism is canonically surjective?

*Notations*:

- $k_T(p)$ means the maximal pro-$p$-extension of $k$ that is unramified outside the set $T$
- $T_\mathfrak{p}(k(p)\mid k)$ denotes the inertia group of $\mathfrak{p} \in k(p)$
- $G(k_T(p) \mid k_S(p))$ is the Galois group of the extension $k_T(p) \mid k_S(p)$
- $T \setminus S(k_S(p))$ are the primes of $T \setminus S$ on the level of $k_S(p)$

Thank you!

Comment: You missed a Latex in the third point; you might want to fix it the next time you need to edit.